# Is there a way to to convert a nested json array into multiple arrays?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

Is there a way to convert a json that looks like this:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "object": [{
        "object_1": "hi",
        "object_2": "hello"
    },
    {
        "object_1": "hello",
        "object_2": "hi"
    }]
}
```

Into something where I can store within each dictionary the parent id without having to change the names like this?

```
{
"id": "1",
"object_1": "hi",
"object_2": "hello"
},
{"id": "1",
"object_1": "hi",
"object_2": "hello"
}
```

Comment: Sure you can! What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways how you can convert the dictionary. For example, use generator:

```
d = {
    "id": "1",
    "object": [{
        "object_1": "hi",
        "object_2": "hello"
    },
    {
        "object_1": "hello",
        "object_2": "hi"
    }]
}
    
def flatten_dict(d):
    for o in d['object']:
        yield {
            'id': d['id'],
            **o
        }

print(list(flatten_dict(d)))
```

Prints:

```
[{'id': '1', 'object_1': 'hi', 'object_2': 'hello'}, {'id': '1', 'object_1': 'hello', 'object_2': 'hi'}]
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot @andrejKesely, this is a duplicate question since it was covered previously but you kept the object names the same which is exactly what I needed